# Optimise select distinct from large table

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

I have a table that contains 320,071,712 number of records, the report that I am currently working on can filter the records by date, after which the number of records come down to 145,878,852. The number of distinct records are 107,311,357.

```
select count(*) 
from [BroadcastOpens] with (nolock) 
where [OpenTimeUtc] >= @StartDate 
and  [OpenTimeUtc] <@EndDate
```

The most time consuming process is SELECT DISTINCT, which took about 40 minutes to run.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [SubscriberId],[OpenTimeUtc]  
FROM [BroadcastOpens] WITH (nolock) 
WHERE [OpenTimeUtc] >= @StartDate 
AND [OpenTimeUtc] <@EndDate
```

I have created both indexes on this table for both column BroadcastId and OpenTimeUtc, they helped to speed up the process, but seems to be less significant.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BroadcastOpens_BroadcastId_Temp] 
ON [dbo].[BroadcastOpens]([BroadcastId])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BroadcastOpens_OpenTimeUtc_Temp] 
ON [dbo].[BroadcastOpens]([OpenTimeUtc])
```

As suggested by Martin Smith, I also have created an indexed view on Table BroadcastOpens grouped by [SubscriberId],[OpenTimeUtc],[BroadcastId].

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwBroadcastOpensRecords
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT [SubscriberId],[OpenTimeUtc],[BroadcastId], COUNT_BIG(*) as tmp    
from [dbo].[BroadcastOpens] group by [SubscriberId],[OpenTimeUtc],   [BroadcastId]  


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_vwBroadcastOpensRecords_Temp ON    
vwBroadcastOpensRecords(SubscriberId, OpenTimeUtc,BroadcastId);
```

This is the step in the query that causes problem
[image]

I am now testing both approaches to see which one yields better performances.

1) No changes to the existing tsql query, no non clustered indexed created. Running on production server ()

[image]

2) No changes to the existing tsql query, created two non clustered indexes on the table. Running on staging server

[image]

3) Create an indexed view, and modified existing tsql query to use this new indexed view to replace table

[image]

4) Merge above two table index into one, rerun the script
[image]

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BroadcastOpens_BroadcastId_Temp] ON [smpro5].[dbo].[BroadcastOpens]([BroadcastId])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BroadcastOpens_OpenTimeUtc_Temp] ON [smpro5].[dbo].[BroadcastOpens]([OpenTimeUtc])
GO

DROP INDEX IX_BroadcastOpens_BroadcastId_Temp ON [smpro5].[dbo].[BroadcastOpens]
GO

DROP INDEX IX_BroadcastOpens_OpenTimeUtc_Temp ON [smpro5].[dbo].[BroadcastOpens]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BroadcastOpens_OpenTimeUtc_BroadcastId_Temp] ON [dbo].[BroadcastOpens]([OpenTimeUtc], [BroadcastId]);
GO
```

Just wondering. the Table BroadcastOpens table gets constantly updated, does this cause concern to the indexed view that I created?

Any suggestion on how to improve this query are appropriated !

Thank you HABO and Martin Smith for your invaluable help !

**NOTE : Don't forget to use WITH (NOEXPAND), when it comes to indexed view !**

Comment: An index on `OpenTimeUtc` that includes `SubscriberId`? See [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Comment: So the table has 320,071,712  rows. Date filter brings down to 145,878,852. How many left after the `DISTINCT`?

Comment: 107,161,812 left after distinct

Comment: A few possibilities would be an indexed view on `OpenTimeUtc, SubscriberId ... GROUP BY OpenTimeUtc, SubscriberId`  which would just be a straight `SELECT` or index on `OpenTimeUtc, SubscriberId` which could feed straight into a stream aggregate and avoid a sort or index on `OpenTimeUtc INCLUDE (SubscriberId)`. But you'd need to consider the overall workload not just that query.

Comment: I have already implemented nonclustered indexes on BroadcastOpens table for both [BroadcastId] and [OpenTimeUtc] columns. Do you consider that this new index view will speed up the process even further? Thanks

Comment: @Jeffrey Did you try it?  You think they commented on something they thought would not work?

Comment: Hi Blam, thank you for your attention on my question. My follow up question was trying to compare the performances of non clustered index to indexed view. It is different from my original question. I would like to thank Martin Smith for all your answers. much appropriate it.

Comment: Hi HABO, thank you very much for your help, yes  I have thought about that and just created to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Removed all DISTINCT keyword
2) Create Non Clustered Index on BroadcastOpens Table to Speed up searching
3) May or May not Create Indexed View

Results : Time spent from 42:32 minutes down to 38:15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Having two seperate indexes isn't very helpfull for this query. Having a covering index should solve your problem:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BroadcastOpens_OpenTimeUtc_BroadcastId_Temp] 
ON [dbo].[BroadcastOpens]([OpenTimeUtc], [BroadcastId]);
```

Comment: Hi MWilemse, thank you very much for the comments. I have also tried that, unfortunately it does not offer better performances. But yes, I should merge these two indexes into one.

Comment: Do you have a table containing all [BroadcastId]'s and/or [OpenTimeUtc]'s. And how does [OpenTimeUtc] look like, is it a date, time or datetime, can de minute and second parts of a time be filled?

Comment: Hi MWilemse, thank you very much for the comments, the table is called BroadcastOpens. OpenTimeUtc has both date and time value. Table is populated already with 320,071,712  number of records.